# H is undefined using Extjs 3.3.1 Tree

Tags: javascript, extjs, tree

I Have Problem With ext-3.3.1 Tree.
I use it in my project but sometimes the browser show this error and fail to load the page.
I take a picture of the errors and It's [here](https://googledrive.com/host/0Bw6XTuR4ocWERTVvdG5Yam9EZWs/Untitled.png) and the html is [here](https://googledrive.com/host/0Bw6XTuR4ocWERTVvdG5Yam9EZWs/error.html).
I really think it made by a bug ! anyone can help?

I hope you can help me it really made me mad.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

The order of javascript file included in Head tag is important. the order should be like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../resources/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../resources/ext/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/openlayers/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/app/theme/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../resources/openlayers/build/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script src="../../resources/geoext/build/GeoExt.js"></script>
```